# 2915ABG wireless adapter on Thinkpad R50e?

Tags: wireless-networking, thinkpad, minipci

I am looking at buying a mini-PCI wireless adapter for an aging Thinkpad R50e.

Those models optionally came with an IBM-branded Intel 2200BG card, but this machine doesn't have one.

Apart from the usual dodgy suppliers on eBay offering counterfeit or broken goods, I can find a 2200BG adapter, but it could cost around £40. I can find a 2915 A/B/G adapter for under £20.

So my question is: will the 2915ABG card work fine with an R50e, or will only the 2200BG card work?

(And obviously, recommendations for reputable suppliers might be helpful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinkwiki has quite a few articles on this. That particular model dosen't seem to on the [list of problematic systems](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_error_01C9_-_More_than_one_Ethernet_devices), though there seems to be a [workaround](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_unauthorized_MiniPCI_network_card), if it is. However i'd also suggest checking if it has a mini pci slot, [since not all models have it](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:R50e)

Comment: The R50 definitely has a mini-PCI slot - it's just empty on this particular machine.

Comment: And it's not going to have Linux on it (it's not mine); I intend to use only an IBM-certified adapter, which is why I'm only considering those two cards - I don't want to start hacking the BIOS.

Comment: thinkwiki is a good resource, even if you don't run linux- especially where you're trying out stuff that you arn't sure about.

Comment: ThinkWiki *is* a good source of info, and tells me that either card will work, so on that basis I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks Journeyman.